# wpdb get_results() returns only 2 rows

Tags: wp-query, database, query, wpdb

I am trying to create custom admin widget to present how many users has registered within last days. I have created function as below:

```
function mdbootstrap_add_dashboard_recent_users(){ 
global $wpdb;

$query = "
    SELECT count(*) as counter, DATE(wp_users.user_registered) as regdate
    FROM wp_users 
    GROUP BY DATE(wp_users.user_registered) 
    ORDER BY DATE(wp_users.user_registered) desc";

$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query,OBJECT);
print_r( $posts);
 }
```

However for some reason it's returning only 2 rows:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [counter] => 1 [regdate] => 2016-01-12 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [counter] => 3 [regdate] => 2016-01-04 ) )
```

Which BTW shows wrong values, as the same query run from PHP MyAdmin gives result as follow:

- counter regdate
- 16 2016-01-13
- 37 2016-01-12
- 51 2016-01-11
- 25 2016-01-10
- 21 2016-01-09
- 26 2016-01-08
- 24 2016-01-07
- 24 2016-01-06
- 18 2016-01-05
- 20 2016-01-04
- 5  2016-01-03

I was looking for similar issue however most of the topics covers issue with only 1 row when people use `get_row` instead of `get_results`. I have played with different parameters like `ARRAY_N`, `OBJECT`, `ARRAY_A` but didn't work - query always returns 2 rows.

Comment: Check result count after remove `GROUP BY DATE(wp_users.user_registered) ` and compare counter value. I know this is not proper steps but we need to check it.

Comment: SELECT count(*) as counter, DATE(wp_users.user_registered) as regdate
 FROM wp_users 
 ORDER BY DATE(wp_users.user_registered) desc" results in 

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [counter] => 4 [regdate] => 2016-01-04 ) )

Comment: From the result `[counter] => 4 [regdate] => 2016-01-04`, Are you sure about result from PHP MyAdmin is correct (into your question)?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have compared table from Wordpress Admin and results from MyAdmin and they match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
SELECT (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM wp_users as temp 
    WHERE DATE(temp.user_registered) = DATE(wp_users.user_registered)
    ) as counter, 
wp_users.*
FROM wp_users
```

Comment: But this doesn't give the same result - it returns list of users while I want to get count per day

Comment: You can sort it by **user_registered** and try below query
`SELECT (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM wp_users as temp 
    WHERE DATE(temp.user_registered) = DATE(wp_users.user_registered)
    ) as counter, 
wp_users.user_registered as registered_date
FROM wp_users`

Comment: Did it worked??

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be related to the way the `DATE()` function is used in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses. When you use `DATE(wp_users.user_registered)` in these clauses, it might not group the records as expected. Instead, try using the `DATE_FORMAT()` function to format the `user_registered` date in a way that's compatible with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Try modify your query below code like

```
function mdbootstrap_add_dashboard_recent_users(){ 

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as counter, DATE_FORMAT(wp_users.user_registered, '%Y-%m-%d') as regdate
FROM wp_users 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(wp_users.user_registered, '%Y-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(wp_users.user_registered, '%Y-%m-%d') DESC";

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

    // Print the results for testing
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo "Date: " . $post->regdate . ", Count: " . $post->counter . "<br>";
    }
}


// Call the function
mdbootstrap_add_dashboard_recent_users();
```